# META REFRESH alternatives

Tags: html, http, redirect

I already know how to use a `meta refresh`, but the problem is that it breaks the back button in some browsers.

Here is a meta refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://google.com/'">
```

I was wondering whether there is an alternative to this?

Comment: META Refresh vs. JavaScript Refresh http://davidwalsh.name/meta-refresh-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use a java script redirect which has a very similar function to the one in the question:

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend PHP, as you can also conditionally redirect.

REDIRECT TO EXAMPLE.COM:

```
<?php header("Location: http://example.com"); ?>
```